# Wordpress Genesis Child Theme Filter divs

Tags: theme-development, filters, genesis-theme-framework, html5

I'm trying to html5ize a Genesis child theme.  So far I've figured out how to replace the Doctype via hook but am having trouble figuring out how i can change the divs to sections and articles without touching the core files.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create all your own templates in a child theme but the core engine does contain the HTML tags and ids.  For me this is the problem with Theme Frameworks (Unless your willing to totally commit to them).

The code quality is outstanding but it's just too much work to roll things your own way.  Just to remove the the genesis and studio press links in the footer you have to write a function remove 2 filters and add an action.

To replace all the divs with your HTML5 tags your going to have to have to write your own functions for

`genesis_site_title()`

`genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap()`

`genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap()`

`genesis_before_content()`

`genesis_after_content()`

`genesis_sidebar()`

`genesis_before_sidebar_widget_area()`

and others

Then do `remove_actions` and `add_filter` depending on the situation.

You can use the visual markup chart to help with your efforts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and direction.  I agree frameworks are a double edged sword, unfortunately this project must be built under genesis per the client :)

Comment: It's a very solid framework you just have to do it there way.  A plugin that made all the changes would be a good idea.  You should post something in there forums.